# How to implement associations for multiple roles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, single-table-inheritance

I am implementing a job search application in rails where A user can signup for three different profiles/roles.

1. Employer
2. Worker
3. Enterpreneur(has his own company)

User can choose more than one profile/role.

(I am using the Devise)

My query is that Is it possible to implement the Single Table Inheritance in the above case.?like

```
  CLass Employer < user
  CLass worker < user
```

or what should be the best solutions for database structure to implement the above feature?

Comment: http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is certainly possible, STI is widely used when models share the same attributes and if you want to be able to query them all together (will help with speed and simplicity since you are loading one db table). You may also share code between the Classes, you only need to put a method once in the parent class and have all the children inherit.

Side note, make sure you are following ruby naming practices, capitalize the classes

```
  Class Worker < User
```

EDIT (suggested approach)

I would not have these roles inherit from the User, you can still use STI but create another model

```
   Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :profiles
   Class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
   Class Employer < Profile
   Class Worker < Profile
   Class Entrepreneur < Profile
```

Comment: @@thanks Kyle for quick reply.Yes I am thinking to implement the STI but as I mentioned in my question that A user can select more then one profiles/roles so in that case How to implement STI.

Comment: yes please I really struggling.If we have any good solutions please suggest me.Because other functionality/good code/database is depends on this important thing.currently I am using rolify gem But i feeling that its not a good solution.

Comment: I am not sure that above solutions will works for me.there should be two tables one is Users and others one is profiles/roles.with many_to_many relationsship.What is your opinion regarding Rolify gem?

Comment: I would suggest using cancan over rolify

Answer (score 0):

You might want to watch this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association) -- this is what I just recently implemented. It uses a bitmask column in the database. I also paired it with [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) to handle my permissions.